# JavaScript: Unable to change input form value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm creating an Intranet site and I need to pass a value that changes depending on what the user clicks.

I thought the best way to get this data to asp.net was to create a form input, just with the type of text, and then change its value in javascript depending on what the user clicks, then in asp.net I would just `request` its value.

The code!

```
<asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="HiddenButton_Click" />
<input type="text" style="display:none" runat="server" id="HiddenValue" value = "hello" />

<div class="admin-page-setting-class" onclick="OptionClicked('userAccounts')">
     View User Accounts
</div>
```

Now the javascript

```
function OptionClicked(option)
{
     alert("hi");
     var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('HiddenValue');

     alert("hi");
     hiddenInput.value = option;

     alert("hi");    

     var btnHidden = $('#<%= HiddenButton.ClientID %>');
     if (btnHidden != null) 
     {
          btnHidden.click();
     }
 }
```

My issue is, it doesn't matter what I try and do I can never change ANY of the values of the input `HiddenValue`. It never gets to the last alert. I'm stumped. How can this not work?

Comment: Do you get any runtime errors? Try `alert(hiddenInput)` or even better `console.log(hiddenInput)`.

Comment: I don't get any errors at all. It doesn't even make it to the alert when I try and change its value, like it just breaks out of the code.

Comment: Okay. So I did `alert(hiddenInput)` and it returned null...

Comment: So there is no element with id `HiddenValue` in you document. Do you know about the buildin developer tools of Browsers like Firefox and Chrome? Use them.

Comment: Your `Id` must be changing. Try this:- `var hiddenInput = $('#<%= HiddenValue.ClientID %>');` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rahul, but it's working now

Answer (score 0):

you use jquery and javascript? or use one or the other

in javascript

```
<script>
        function OptionClicked(option) {
            document.getElementById('HiddenValue').value = option;
            document.getElementById('HiddenButton').click();            
        }
    </script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenValue" runat="server" />

        <asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="HiddenButton_Click" />
<div class="admin-page-setting-class" onclick="OptionClicked('userAccounts')">
         View User Accounts
    </div>
</form>
```

In server, your behind code

```
protected void HiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string yourData = HiddenValue.Text;
    }
```

in jquery

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".admin-page-setting-class").click(function () {
            $('#HiddenValue').val($(".admin-page-setting-class").text());
            $('#HiddenButton').click();
        });
    });

</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenValue" runat="server" />

    <asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="HiddenButton_Click" />

    <div class="admin-page-setting-class">
         View User Accounts
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the issue has been resolved. My MasterPage was automatically changing all ID values, the end result meaning my `GetElementByID` not working. Thank though